# Is the quotient map of a normed vector space always open?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $M$ be a closed subspace of the normed vector space $V$, and let $\pi: V \rightarrow V/M$ be the quotient map. Is this necessarily open, or do we require some other hypotheses on $V$ or $M$? (For example, if $V$ is Banach then the Open Mapping Theorem would immediately imply that $\pi$ is open.)

There appears to have been some discussion of the problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61173/when-quotient-map-is-open), but that was for general topological spaces. (Also, it seems that the question itself was not answered... it seems that the conclusion is *if* a continuous surjective map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is open, then it is a quotient map, which is sort of the converse of what I'm asking.) Anyway, I'm wondering if perhaps the extra constraints on $M$ and $V$, namely that they're vector spaces, is enough to conclude what we want.

Comment: I don't think it will be true without more constraints than just $M$ being closed in a normed space $V$. E.g. completeness is crucial in the proof of the open mapping theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, $\pi$ is an open map. Let $U$ be open and $y \in \pi(U)$. Then $y=\pi (x)$ for some $x \in U$. There exists $r>0$ such that $B(x,r) \subset U$. Let us show that $\|w-y\|<r$ implies $w \in \pi (U)$. For any such $w$ we can write $w= \pi (z)$ fro some $z$ so we get $\|\pi(z)-\pi (x)\|<r$. By definition of the norm in the quotient space this implies $\|z-x-m\|<r$ for some $m \in M$. We now get $z-m \in U$ so $\pi(z-m) \in \pi (U)$. But $\pi(m)=0$ so we get $w=\pi (z) \in \pi(U)$ as required.