# $H$ closed implies $G / H$ Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, quotient-spaces

Let $G$ be a topological group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. It is to show that the closedness of $H$ implies $G/H$ being a Hausdorff space.

We denote the projection map $G \to G/H$ with $p$.

My book gives the following proof:

Let H be closed. Then, the preimage of H under the continuous map
$$G \times G \to G, (g, g') \mapsto  g^{-1}g'$$
is closed too. This is the set of pairs $(g, g')$ with $gH = g'H$, i. e. the equivalence relation belnging to the surjection $p$. Since $p$ is also open, the equivalence relation's closedness implies that the quotient is a Hausdorff space.

I do not understand the last sentence. Given two different points in $G/H$, how to find concretely disjoint neighbourhoods in $G/H$ and why do we need the function, since its domain is a product, not G itself? Why is $p$ open and how do we can conclude from this the Hausdorff property?

I have found a similar question here, but the way of proof was rather different. And yes, it's embarrassing not being able to understand a detailed simple proof. :-)

Note: On Wikipedia, I found that (applied to this situation) $ker(p)$ closed implies $G/H$ Hausdorff. This would ease the proof dramatically, but my book did not prove this fact.

Comment: What is ${}p{}$?

Comment: The projection map. I edited the question to include that piece of information.

Comment: Looks like your textbook is using the following: If $\sim$ is an **open** equivalence relation, then $X/{\sim}$ is Hausdorff iff $\{(x,y)\mid x\sim y\} $ is closed in $X\times X $.

Comment: This has a proof of the above and more https://mathstrek.blog/2013/03/23/topology-quotients-of-topological-groups/

Comment: The quotient map of a group action is open: see the comments to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61173/when-quotient-map-is-open)